# Deploying frontend

Tags: deployment, frontend, mern, render.com

After I deployed my backend program, I tried to deploy my front-end program. However, it did not go well. I do not know which information I should give, so I will list what I have done so far below:

- I created both the backend and frontend of the program. https://github.com/makimakiver/tuba
- I could deploy the backend program on render.com.
- I cannot deploy the frontend of my program, and the website gave me this "The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process."

I simply want to deploy my app by solving the error which I mentioned. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I cloned your repo and set my backend URL it's working fine.

If you're seeing this error while building or running a React application, there are several potential causes and solutions you can consider:

**Insufficient Memory:** Especially when building large React applications or when utilizing tools like Webpack, the process might consume a lot of memory, causing the system to kill it.

**Solution:** You can increase the available memory. If you're using a local development environment, consider closing unnecessary applications to free up RAM. If you're on a virtual machine or cloud environment, consider resizing to an instance with more RAM.

**Node.js Memory Limit:** By default, Node.js has a memory limit (usually 1.76 GB for 64-bit and 512 MB for 32-bit machines). If your build process exceeds this, it will fail.

**Solution:** Increase the Node.js memory limit using the --max-old-space-size flag. For instance, to increase to 4 GB, you can run:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 npm run build
```

**External Interruptions:** As the error suggests, someone or something might have killed the process.

**Solution:** Ensure no other scripts or processes are interfering with the build process. If you're on a shared system, make sure no one else is terminating your processes.

**Dependencies:** Outdated or incompatible dependencies can sometimes cause unexpected build failures.

**Solution:** Update your dependencies to their latest versions. Always make sure to test your application after updates. Use the following commands:

```
npm update
npm audit fix
```

Can you share on which server, are you trying to post the application?